# How to add the MediaStream obtained from GetUserMedia to an <audio> tag?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio, getusermedia

I have obtained the audio `stream` using `navigator.getUserMedia()`, but when I try to add it to an audio source, its not working.
Below is the implementation:

```
addMediaStreamToAudioTag : function(stream) { 
    var audioContainer = document.querySelector('#audio'); //audio element 
    if(audioContainer) {
        audioContainer.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); //TODO does not work this way 
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is not working ?
The same works when I use a video element instead of an audio element. Why ?

Comment: Seems to work just fine [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Leknse5L/). just had to add the `play()` method after attaching the stream to the source of the audio element.

Comment: @DavidDomain..thank you so much. It works now

Comment: Great, no problem. Have fun.

Comment: Go ahead and add that as an answer and mark it as accepted!

Comment: You can also use `<audio autoplay></audio>`.